# What is the appropriate usage of the idiom using 'set ..'?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, idioms, phrasal-verbs

I came across the following question in a textbook.  All are about the idiom using 'set', and the answer was found to be "set out". I looked each over in the dictionary and I found 'set out', 'set in' and 'set off' all have the meaning 'to start'. Why is only 'set out' correct in this case?

> Question: Choose the appropriate words to fill in the blank.
>
> In this book, the author ____ ___ to prove that the inhabitants of the islands came from Japan.
>
> Choice of words:  *sets in*  /  *sets out*  /  *sets off*  /  *sets up*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrases *sets in*, *sets out*, *sets off*, and *sets up* have similar but distinctive idiomatic senses as intransitive verb phrases, which I would express as follows:

- ***sets in:*** arrives, becomes fixed, or begins to take effect. *Example:* It will be harder to plow the fields when winter **sets in**.
- ***sets out:*** undertakes, or begins to make an effort. *Example:* Once he **sets out** to answer a question, he won't rest until he has succeeded.
- ***sets off:*** departs, *Example:* Every morning at dawn, she **sets off** for her job 5 miles away.
- ***sets up:*** prepares for business or for use (this is more often a transitive verb phrase, but it can be used intransitively in some situations) *Example:* He brings his goods to the market stall each day and then **sets up** for business.

*The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2011) offers the following more formal definitions for each phrase:

> **set in: 1.** To insert: *set in the sleeve of a gown*. **2.** To begin to happen or be apparent: "*Evening was setting in as I as I took the road over Mountain Top*" (Charles Siebert).
>
> **set out: 1.** To begin an earnest attempt; undertake: *He set out to understand why the plan had failed*. **2.** To lay out systematically or graphically: *set out a terrace*. **3.** To display for exhibition or sale. **4.** To plant: *set out seedlings*. **5.** To start a journey: *She set out at dawn for town*.
>
> **set off: 1a.** To give rise to; cause to occur: *set off a chemical reaction*. **b.** To cause to explode: *set off a bomb*. **c.** To make suddenly or demonstrably angry: *The clerk's indifference finally set me off*. **2.** To indicate as being different; distinguish: *features setting him off from the crowd*. **3.** To direct attention to by contrast; accentuate: *set off a passage with italics*. **4.** To counterbalance, counteract, or or compensate for: *Our dismay at her leaving was set off by our knowing that she was happy*. **5.** To start on a journey: *set off for Europe*.
>
> **set up: 1.** To place in an upright position. **2a.** To elevate; raise. **b.** To raise in authority or power; invest with power: *They set up the general as a dictator*. **c.** To put oneself forward as; claim to be: *He has set himself up as as an authority on the English language*. **d.** To assemble and erect: *set up a new machine*. **3.** To establish; found: *set up a new charity*. **4.** To cause: *They set up howls of protest over new taxes*. **5.** To establish in business by providing capital, equipment, or other backing. **6.** *Informal* **a.** To treat (someone) to drinks. **b.** To pay for (drinks). **7.** *Informal* To stimulate or exhilarate: *a victory that really set the team up*. **8.** To lay plans for: *set up a kidnapping*. **9.** *Informal* To put (someone else) into a compromising situation by deceit or trickery: *Swindlers have set me up*. **10.** *Sports* To make a pass to (a teammate), creating a scoring opportunity.

The key to negotiating this mass of definitions is to look for options that involve intransitive verbs, the form needed to complete the original sentence: "The author ____ ____ to prove..." Quickly we can winnow the relevant *American Heritage* definitions down to *sets in* definition 2; *sets out* definitions 1 and 5; *sets off* definitions 4 and 5; and *sets up* definition 5 (arguably).

The author doesn't begin to happen or begin to be apparent to prove X, so *sets in* is no good as the answer. The author doesn't counteract or counterbalance to prove X and doesn't start on a journey to prove X (except in a rather strained figurative sense), so *sets off* looks pretty unsatisfactory. And the author doesn't set up in business to prove X (except, again, in a strained figurative sense), so we can discard *sets up*.

That leaves *sets out*, and the first *American Heritage Dictionary* definition—"To begin an earnest attempt; undertake"—seems exactly on point: The author begins an earnest attempt or undertakes to prove X. It's true that you could push the figurative meaning "start a journey" (which is no better or worse than the intransitive meaning of *set off* we considered earlier)—but you don't need to do that. You already have a more suitable definition of *set out* confirming *sets out* as the right phrase.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *set out* has also the meaning of:

> Aim or intend to do something
>   https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/set

This is the meaning required in the given sentence (unless they wanted to say that the author started to prove a point, then went on to do other things).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  In the latter case ( the auther started to prove ...), can 'set off' or 'set in' also be used?

Comment: You could use *set off*, but not *set in*.

Comment: Can I ask why not?  I found 'set in' also has the meaning 'start' as set off (out) does in a dictionary.

Comment: *set in* can be used to describe something that begins to exist (such as a season or a disease, usually something unwanted), not someone that starts to do something.